# how to pass sql query to procedure as a parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure sqldynamic(sqlquery sys_refcursor)
is 
cursor c1 is sqlquery;
begin
open c1;

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to pass SQL query as parameter, try the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sqldynamic (sqlquery IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
   LOOP
      FETCH sqlquery INTO <your variables>;
      EXIT WHEN sqlquery %NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

END
```

and execute the above procedure as

```
DECLARE
   my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cursor FOR
      SELECT  <columns>
      FROM <your_table>;
   sqldynamic (my_cursor);
   CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
```

Substitute whatever deemed necessary inside `<>`

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sqldynamic (sqlquery IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
   v_emp_number   employees.emp_number%TYPE;
   v_emp_name     employees.employee_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      FETCH sqlquery INTO v_emp_number, v_emp_name;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
     'v_emp_number   ' || v_emp_number || '  v_emp_name  ' || v_emp_name);
      EXIT WHEN sqlquery%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

And execute the above procedure as a PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
   my_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT emp_number, employee_name FROM employees WHERE emp_number=108;

   sqldynamic (my_cursor);

   CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to open the cursor, it is already open. Just make

```
create or replace procedure sqldynamic(sqlquery sys_refcursor) is 
begin
   LOOP
      FETCH sqlquery INTO ...;
      EXIT WHEN sqlquery%NOTFOUND; 
      ...
   END LOOP;

end;
```

You would call the procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
   curSel SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN curSel FOR ...;
   sqldynamic(curSel);

END;
```